# Differences between using Resource Model (Tastypie) and single Rest-Framework function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

First of all, I am new to Python and Django, I am trying to understand the pros/cons of apis by single function and apis by resources (Tastypie's ModelResources).

I had been working on a Django project and been using rest-framework along all the way. However, I created each function for each api from the server. For example, this is a simple register function I wrote using rest-framework:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def register(request):
    if request.data is not None:
       try:
           username = request.data['username']
           password = request.data['password']
           user = User.objects.create_user
                            (username=utils.encrypt(username),
                             password=utils.encrypt(password))
           ......
```

This is another register example using Tastypie's ModelResource:

```
class RegisterUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'register'

    .......
    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
       try:
            username = bundle.data["username"]
            password = bundle.data["password"]

            if User.objects.filter(username=username):
                raise CustomBadRequest(
                    code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    message="This username is taken"
                )

            # Create object
            bundle.obj = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            bundle.obj.save()

            # Create user profile object
            UserInfo.objects.create(user=bundle.obj)
        except KeyError:
            raise CustomBadRequest(
                code="missing_key",
                message="Must provide {missing_key} when creating a user."
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return bundle
```

Please help me to understand what are the differences between those two ways and which way is better. I personally think using Tastypie's ModelResource is pretty complicated and sometime hard to control object's permission (I could PATCH any object by id even that object was not created by me -- I tried to find those info in the Tastypie's documentations but haven't found something related)..